# IE 10 Apache/Linux HTTP/1.0 412 Precondition Failed video.js loading mp4 video

Tags: internet-explorer, apache2, internet-explorer-10, video.js

We have a interesting problem, when we have this combination of stuff:

IE 10 (sometimes IE 9 also)
Apache 2.2/Linux (RH EL 6.3) running https
video.js player
mp4 video file

When we have this combination of things the video player shows a spinning icon.

When we examine the http headers we see:
request:

```
GET /tmp/Question123.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Accept */*
If-Unmodified-Since Thu, 11 Jul 2013 19:49:44 GMT
If-Match W/"a074e-50228d-4e141b21b6cfb" 
Range bytes=49152-5251724
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; MALC)
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG 1
Pragma getIfoFileURI.dlna.org
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host: mysite.com
Connection Keep-Alive
```

response:

```
HTTP/1.0 412 Precondition Failed
```

On IE 8 it seems to use flash so we have a different path and it works.
On Firefox/Chrome/Safari, everything works fine.

The only thing we can see that may be causing this is:
Firefox uses:

```
If-Modified-Since   Thu, 11 Jul 2013 19:58:37 GMT
If-None-Match   "a074e-50228d-4e141d1edc1b6"
```

These are different request headers.

Any ideas?

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by these request headers:

```
If-Unmodified-Since Thu, 11 Jul 2013 19:49:44 GMT
If-Match W/"a074e-50228d-4e141b21b6cfb"
```

The server says "no, my current version of that resource doesn't meet those criteria, so I'll return a HTTP/412 response to let you know that."

Those headers are there because the client is making a HTTP RANGE request (asking for only part of the file) and thus it needs to ensure that the portion of the file it's getting back from the server is from the same version of the file for which it already has a part.

What are the HTTP response headers on the original response? Does the ETAG header on the response properly have quotation marks wrapping its value? Is there only a single server or are you load-balancing requests across multiple servers?

Comment: single server, let me see if I can find the headers, I found a work around, by setting the date of the file an hour ago each time, it seems to disable this cache failure for now.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue on my current project by updating Lib.Web.Mvc to the latest version (6.4.1). It looks like this library was sending response headers back to IE that it did not like.